# Delphi 2010 - Watchfolder - Check if a file is in use - Add item to listbox while the listbox is in loop

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to make a watchfolder application using Delphi 2010.
On the main form I added 2 listbox and a timer.
I list all files from a specific folder.
At every 5 seconds i perform a check over the files from a listbox to see which file is still in use.
Listbox1 holds the files that are in use and listbox2 holds the files that are not in use.
If there is a file that is being used(ex: it is still being copied to the folder) i add it to listbox1.
If the files from that folder that i monitor are not in use then I add them to listbox2.
The problem is that I perform a loop over listbox2 in order to send all the files listed to a ftp (for i:=0 to listbox2.items.count-1 do ....).
If i add one more file to listbox2 while performing the loop I get the "List index out of bounds"?
How can i add an item to listbox2 loop while performing the loop?
Thanks a lot?
Any other suggestion regarding the watchfolder ideea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop's control value is evaluated only once, at the beginning of the loop. Adding entries to the list should not be causing a bounds error, as the `Count` will not be shrinking.  The loop will stop when it reaches the old `Count`. However, removing an item would shrink the `Count` and thus cause a bounds error once the loop exceeds the new `Count` trying to reach the old `Count`.

That being said, the solution is simple - DO NOT modify the ListBox while you are looping through its content! You will have to either:

1. delay any modifications until after the loop has finished.
2. copy the current ListBox content to a separate TStringList and loop through that instead of the ListBox directly, then you can do whatever you want to the ListBox while the loop is busy.

Comment: Thank you. One more question? How to evaluate when loop has ended?

Comment: Um, when the loop stops running? I don't understand what you are asking. Do you even understand how loops work? [Control Loops](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Control_Loops)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link. I'll study it. I'm just a beginner in programming. I have a lot to learn.